# AngularJS belongsTo-hasMany relationship

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

I am trying to learn using AngularJs with Laravel. I have read and watched many tuts but I could not find any for using Laravel relationships. I have belongsTo-many relationships between my Post and Author model.When using blade I can get author names using `{{$post->author->name}}`

Now I am trying to get for angularjs.

```
    class Post extends Eloquent {
    public function author()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('Author');
        }
    }

    class Author extends Eloquent { 
     public function posts()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('Post');
        }
    }

class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex(){
        $posts = Post::where('id','<','10')->get();
        return Response::json($posts);
    }

}
```

With the js files :

```
// public/js/controllers/mainCtrl.js
angular.module('mainCtrl', [])
    .controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, Post) { 
        $scope.postsData = {};
        // loading variable to show the spinning loading icon
        $scope.loading = true;

        Post.get()
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.posts = data;
                $scope.loading = false;
            });
           //dont know how to get author here in foreach method 
           angular.forEach($scope.posts,function(post)...


    });

// public/js/services/commentService.js
angular.module('postService', [])
    .factory('Post', function($http) {

        return {
            // get all the posts
            get : function() {
                return $http.get('/api/posts/');
            }
        }
    });

<div class="comment" ng-hide="loading" ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <h3>Comment #{{ post.id }} </h3> <p>{{post.title}}</p>
        {{post.author_id}} / {{post.author.name}}
</div>
```

I am close to solution but still confused how do I get the author name in Post service. Any helps are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your user controller, eager load the author when retrieving the posts, this will allow it to be accessed in angular via `post.author`

```
public function getIndex(){
    $posts = Post::with('author')->where('id','<','10')->get();
    return Response::json($posts);
}
```